# Automatically decorate every method in a class

Tags: php, design-patterns, decorator

I would like to add some logic before and after every time I'm using a method (doesn't really matter if is private, protected or public) in a class.

For example:

```
class Service 
{
    function test1() {
        Log:start(__METHOD__);
        someLogicInThere(); ....
        Log:end(__METHOD__);
    }

    function test2() {
        Log:start(__METHOD__);
        someLogicInThere(); ....
        Log:end(__METHOD__);
    }
    ...
}
```

My idea is to finally have something like this:

```
/**
 * @LogDecorate
 */
class Service
{
    function test1() {
        someLogicInThere();
    }

    function test2() {
        someLogicInThere();
    }
    ...
}
```

Use annotations is not important. There is any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your question-title already suggests, you could use the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for this. I'm not quite sure though if a full-stack Decorator pattern is necessary here. If it's a really simple use-case, something like this could suffice.

What you could do, is extend the class and 'route' all calls to the extended class. Then add some logic before and after, and call the parent method in between. Something like this:

```
class Service {
    function method1() {
        doSomeFunkyStuff();
    }

    function method2() {
        doSomeOtherFunkyStuff();
    }
}

class DecoratedService extends Service {
    function method1() {
        Log::start(__METHOD__);
        parent::method1();
        Log::end(__METHOD__);
    }

    function method2() {
        Log::start(__METHOD__);
        parent::method2();
        Log::end(__METHOD__);
    }
}

$service = new DecoratedService();
$service->method1();
$service->method2();
```

Now you can either choose to use the original `Service` or use the `DecoratedService`. The funcionality is the same, and the `DecoratedService` will not have to be altered if the `Service` changes, assuming the method names won't change (which would actually be a bad thing).

But also look to the wiki page (or any other resource) to understand fully what's the intent of the Decorator Pattern. This (above) might not be the ideal solution for your problem.

**EDIT** a bit more automatic as requested, sir.

As you cannot change the visibility of methods, using the magic `__call()` doesn't work (as public or protected parent methods will be accessible from the child as well). But, what you *can* do, is create your own call method!

```
class DecoratedService extends Service {
    function call($method) {
        if(!method_exists(parent, $method)) {
            return false; // OR:
            throw Exception;
            // OR handle this case some other way
        }

        Log::start(array(parent, $method));
        call_user_func(array(parent, $method));
        Log::end(array(parent, $method));
    }        
}

$service = new DecoratedService;
$service->call('method1');
```

Comment: I would like to use something more automatic. My classes are already created and create a Decorator for every class will be a nightmare

Comment: well, you should either create a decorator-like class for every class you want to add this functionality, or just live with it. To create something like this that would log EVERY call to EVERY object of EVERY class is hacky and VERY unadvisable.

Comment: What's the 'hacky' solution?

Comment: well, you could ie. overwrite the [spl_autoload_register()](http://tr1.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) method to add functionality to (decorate) classes. But I can't warn you enough: this is VERY hacky and you should NOT even try this...

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it is a typicall case of Smart Reference Pattern (some mix of Proxy and Decorator Patterns).

```
class A {
    function test1() {
        echo 'TEST 1', PHP_EOL;
    }

    function test2() {
        echo 'TEST 1', PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class ProxyA {
    protected $wrapped;

    public function __construct($wrapped) {
        $this->wrapped = $wrapped;
    }

    public function __call($name, $args) {
        echo 'Log:start';
        $this->wrapped->$name($args);
        echo 'Log:end';
    }
}

$proxy = new ProxyA(new A());
$proxy->test1();
```

But it works only for public methods.

Mixing Smart Reference with DecoratedService::call() method from @giorgio and @yceruto answer can cover all method, or just implement __call() twice:

```
class A {
    public function test1() {
        echo 'TEST 1', PHP_EOL;
    }

    private function test2() {
        echo 'TEST 2', PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function __call($name, $args) {
        if (method_exists($this, $name)) {
            $this->$name($args);
        }
    }
}

class ProxyA {
    protected $wrapped;

    public function __construct($wrapped) {
        $this->wrapped = $wrapped;
    }

    public function __call($name, $args) {
        if (method_exists($this->wrapped, $name)) {
            echo 'Log:start';
            $this->wrapped->$name($args);
            echo 'Log:end';
        }
    }
}

$proxy = new ProxyA(new A());
$proxy->test0(); // Nothing to do
$proxy->test1(); // Done
$proxy->test2(); // Done
```

Answer (score -1):

Use of the magic __call method might make this easy for you:

```
class Service 
{
    public function test1() {
        echo 'TEST 1', PHP_EOL;
    }

    protected function test2() {
        echo 'TEST 2', PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function __call($method, $args) {
        echo 'Some stuff before', PHP_EOL;
        $returnValue = $this->$method($args);
        echo 'Some stuff after', PHP_EOL;
        return $returnValue;
    }
}

$x = new Service();
$x->test2();
$x->test1();
```

Note that if the method is accessible from outside the class (like `test1`) then `__call()` won't be invoked; it only executes if the methods involved are protected or private; and doesn't trigger if they are invoked internally within the object either

Comment: I can't change the type of every method.